# How to call this class?

Tags: java

I have my main class which invokes a custom JFrame class called MainFrame

```
public class App {

public static MainFrame mf;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             MainFrame mf = new MainFrame(Workers); //jFrame
        }   
    }); 
}

public static void foo(String s){ //invoked by another class
    mf.validate();

}       
}
```

A method calling for mf outside outside of run() returns a null value. How can I invoke a method inside of MainFrame?

Comment: As a side note, if you can at all avoid it you don't want shared mutable state, especially anything in a `static` variable.  When possible, give it to the needing instance (note that this _can_ still be dangerous, but at least you've made the explicit choice of who to share it with).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to declare your class outside of the method scope in order to use it later.

```
MainFrame mf;

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mf  = new MainFrame(Workers); //jFrame
    }   
});
```

It is happening because of a thing called *scope*. Your variable is alive only in the brackets where it was declared. After that the garbage collector automatically removes it.

Comment: You guys are super fast. Thank you so much, it's been driving me crazy. It won't even let me accept the answer this quick. A+

Answer (score 3):

you have already declared `MainFrame mf;` outside

so just replace this statement

```
MainFrame mf = new MainFrame(Workers);
```

with

```
 mf  = new MainFrame(Workers); //jFrame
```

inorder to access the object outside of run()

Answer (score 1):

Declare the class outside of the method. Like this:

```
MainFrame mf;

// following actions...
```